# Make absolutely positioned divs 50% height of their parent on IE9+

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I'm trying to make a couple divs span the entire height of their container (which is a table-cell and has a variable height). I want each div to be 50% of its parent, and I also want them to be one on top of the other. What I do is to absolutely position the top one as **top: 0; bottom: 50%;** and the bottom one as **bottom: 0; top: 50%**. This approach works just fine on most browsers but on IE9+.

This is what my layout looks like on Chrome, Firefox and Safari (and surprisingly, IE8 as well) and what I get on IE9+ instead:

[image: Make absolutely positioned divs 50% height of their parent on IE9+]

For some reason, these two absolutely positioned divs overlap on Internet Explorer.

Here's my markup:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
        Bacon ipsum dolor amet short ribs shankle cupim strip steak shank bresaola bacon. Corned beef tri-tip turkey boudin. Strip steak short ribs meatloaf bacon shank kielbasa prosciutto. Pork chop picanha drumstick kielbasa jerky shankle strip steak beef ribs tenderloin pig tail landjaeger turducken.
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="top">TOP DIV</div>
        <div class="bottom">BOTTOM DIV</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And these are my styles:

```
.table {
  display: table;
  background-color: #cbcbcb;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;

  &:first-of-type {
    width: 30%;
  }
}

.bottom,
.top {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.top {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Here's a bin to play around with: http://jsbin.com/yifeqe/edit?html,css,output

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that `position:absolute` is blocking your divs in IE, so you see only bottom div.

IE doesn't take to position absolute that kindly, so you have to use:

```
display:inline-block;
```

instead.

Here is an updated jsfiddle.

[IE Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/opLx68yb/10/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Setting the divs to `display: inline-block` and taking `position: absolute` off won't do the trick in this case since I need them both (as a whole) to span all the way up and down of the containing cell: http://i.imgur.com/gAE61V7.png. Can't afford not to absolutely position them since `top` and `bottom` won't have any effect then.

Comment: Edited the code, seems to work with position absolute, but IE cannot work correct with your bottom: %;